# What does $D^n$ refer to?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

I'm not sure what object $D^n$ is in the following exercise:

"Write down an explicit homeomorphism between $D^n/S^{n-1}$ and $S^n$."

Thanks!

Comment: It should mean the $n$-disk

Comment: Closed $n$-dimensional ball.